# Connecting to localhost & local network simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, localhost, development-environment

When developing my front-end having used `create-react-app`, I can connect to it on my local machine using `http://localhost:3000/` or on my network using `http://192.168.1.160:3000/`. My back-end (NodeJS/Express) is also on my local machine on `http://localhost:5000/`.

On my front-end, I have the URL to my back-end stored in an env variable as `http://localhost:5000/`. The problem is when I connect to my front-end from my mobile(on my network using `http://192.168.1.160:3000/`), it does not recognize `http://localhost:5000/`. I'm guessing it is because I have to use `http://192.168.1.160:5000/` to connect to the back-end on my network.

This seems to require changing the back-end URL in my env file every time I want to test it out on mobile. Is there a way I can connect to my front and back-end from both my local machine and my network without having to constantly change the URL?

Comment: `http://localhost:5000` is equivalent to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.  this address is called the "loopback", which is connecting to the machine's own network card directly.  When you are running the server and browser on the same machine, this isn't a problem.  However, when you are running the server and browser on different devices (phones, tablets, etc), `localhost` will never work.  `localhost` is exclusively used in local testing, it is never used in distributed testing or in production.

Comment: @Claies is it safe if I just change every localhost address in my app to 192.168.1.160 for development purposes and just connect to 192.168.1.160 even from my local machine?

Comment: that would work, assuming that your IP address stays the same.  The main benefit of using `localhost` is that you don't have to worry about if your machine's IP changes, or even if your machine doesn't have an IP address at all.  Obviously, though, if you are testing networked features, you need to have an IP address.  You could also refer to your machine by it's hostname rather than it's IP, assuming you have a decent router that translates hostnames in local DNS......

Comment: Ok thanks! I appreciate the help.